# JPA : No connection specified for the project

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I followed the following lesson step by step:

> http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-datasource/h2-database-tutorial

I chose the database to be persisted in a file.

But I receive the following error under "Markers" :

> No connection specified for the project. No data-specific validation will be performed

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you talking about Eclipse Markers ?

Comment: @XavierCoulon: he/she apparently is - this particular marker could benefit from a link to the Project properties > JPA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "*No connection specified for project. No database-specific validation will be performed*" [Eclipse Marker](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-11.htm?cp=0_2_6) is related to JPA.

You can perform one of the following things to eliminate this marker:

1.Add the required datatools.

2.Disable the JPA validator on `Project Properties` → `Validation`.

Comment: disabling the validator is like closing your eye(and saying all my codes are valid). secondly, what are the required datatools which needs to be added. Thanks

Answer (score 36):

Right Click on the project > Properties > JPA. There you can define a connection (follow the wizard).

Answer (score 3):

If your connection is managed by the Application Server, you can ignore this message by going to `Project` -> `Properties` -> `JPA` -> `Errors / Warnings` :

- Check `Enable Project Specific Settings` .
- Under `Project` tree set `No connection specified for project` to `Ignore`.